# Using a for loop to rename processed .wav file with pydub AudioSegment function

Tags: python, glob, wav, pydub

I am trying to rename multiple files in a loop using the AudioSegment function. Below is the function for a single file (which works perfectly

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("./OM1/BMM.wav")

new_audio = audio[1000:len(audio)-1000] 
new_audio.export('newSong.wav', format="wav")
```

Now I want to loop through the whole folder but it seems to give me just one folder

```
i = 1
for wave_file in glob.glob("./OM1/*.wav"):   #Folder containing subject files 
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wave_file)
    new_sound = sound[1000:len(audio)-1000] 
    new_sound.export('newSong.wav', format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for wave_file in glob.glob("/*.wav"):    
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wave_file)
    extract = sound[10:len(audio)-10] 
    #extract = sound[1000:len(audio)-1000] 
    extract.export(wave_file+'-extract.wav', format="wav")
    print(wave_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your variable names are mixed up. look at this:

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(wave_file)
new_sound = sound[1000:len(audio)-1000] 
new_audio.export('newSong.wav', format="wav")
```

it looks like your last line should be:

```
new_sound.export('newSong.wav', format="wav")
```

also, obviously all of your output files cannot be named `newSong.wav`

Comment: Yeah, that was some editing issue. I want the for loop to export multiple files

Comment: did you try fixing the names and rerunning?

Comment: yes the names are already fixed in my main code

Comment: @ReubenNewtonAddison what happens when you run it?